# Continuing batch file after executing jar

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, glassfish

I'm trying to run a batch script that would create a new glassfish domain (v 3.1) and **right after** the creation it would continue with some administrative tasks, like removing other directories or copying files to the newly-created domain. Problem is, I have to wait until the glassfish intallation script finishes its work. I have tried to create a new window with:

```
Start /WAIT "" asadmin --user admin --interactive=false create-domain   --adminport 4848  --instanceport 8080  --nopassword new_domain
```

and running some simple commands (like xcopy, rd) after it, in the same .bat file. The problem is, after the asadmin script has finished its work new window does not close, but stays opened and the whole script hangs waiting for the job to terminate. I can close it manually and the script continues its flow, but this solution is not satisfactory. I have even tried to modify the asadmin.bat script to force it to shutdown after creation in this way:

```
%JAVA% -jar "%~dp0..\glassfish\modules\admin-cli.jar" %* && exit
exit
```

But it does not help.

Comment: i'm not sure but try to call instead Start ...call /WAIT "" asadmin --user admin --interactive=false create-domain   --adminport 4848  --instanceport 8080  --nopassword new_domain

Comment: Replacing start with call and removing /wait flags solves the issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comment already suggested you have to use `call` instead of `Start` and you don't need that `/WAIT` flag:

```
echo "Start..."
call asadmin --user admin --interactive=false create-domain   --adminport 4848  --instanceport 8080  --nopassword new_domain
xcopy something...
// more
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `call` rather than `Start`

```
call asadmin --user admin --interactive=false create-domain   --adminport 4848  --instanceport 8080  --nopassword new_domain
```

when the jar is done executing, control returns to the batch script.